# Case when date = current_date then text

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, case

I have a table like this:

```
| id | token_date |
|----|------------|
| 10 | 2020-03-24 |
| 14 | 2020-03-25 |
| 16 | 2020-03-26 |
|  9 | 2020-03-26 |
| 21 | 2020-03-27 |
| 25 | 2020-03-28 |
```

But when I execute this query:

```sql
SELECT token_date = CURRENT_DATE AS "is_equal",
       CASE
          WHEN token_date=CURRENT_DATE THEN 'TODAY'
          ELSE token_date
       END AS "result"
FROM DATA
```

I get this result:

```
| is_equal |     result |
|----------|------------|
|    false | 2020-03-24 |
|    false | 2020-03-25 |
|     true | 2020-03-26 |
|     true | 2020-03-26 |
|    false | 2020-03-27 |
|    false | 2020-03-28 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c29a7e/4)

I would expect that in the rows where `is_equal` is `true`, the result should be `TODAY`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it, but I don't want to discard the question. The solution is to `CAST(token_date as varchar)` in the else clause

Edit: See @a_horse_with_no_name 's comment - it is better to use the `to_char` function to format the date to get a consistent output.
E.g. `to_char(token_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: By casting the date you are relying on an implicit formatting. If you need as specific date format, it might be better to use `to_char(token_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` to make sure this will return the same string regardless of any locale settings

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know, but StackOverflow won't let me until tomorrow...